How do I get information from a contract?
How do you obtain information from a deployed contract? I know it is possible because I have seen a screenshot that showed detailed information about some of the interactions with a contract.
The specific contract is a DeFi that allows users to take out loans, and the screenshot showed the amount to be lent, the addresses involved, the loan interest...
How do you obtain that information?
